# Is it possible to partially calculate the graphs of Open Trip Planner?

Tags: gtfs, opentripplanner

I have a question about Open Trip Planner. In the project I'm working on I've automated the download of GTFS files whenever an update is available.

Every time my server downloads a new update, however, it is recreating the entire graph (including the map and the GTFS that have not been modified).

Is it possible to update only the graphs related to specific GTFS in OTP?

In the guide it says that it is possible to save graphs, but this part of the tutorial is very poor, or maybe I cannot find it.

link to guide I am referring: http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Basic-Tutorial/

I am using the following command to start OTP:

```
java -Xmx512m -jar "/otp-1.4.0-shaded.jar" --build "/downloads" --inMemory
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: No, I had to change my initial project. My idea was to use OTP and GTFS also for a kind of shuttle for on demand request transportation. This is not the purpose of GTFS, so I experimented if it was possible anyway. I couldn't achieve my objective and now I am using OR-Tools that looks more appropriate. Link: https://developers.google.com/optimization